# play h264 video using pygame

Tags: video, pygame, h.264

I'm doing the GUI for raspberry pi enabled project using pygame and an HDMI LCD touchscreen. I can record h264 video using a compatible camera but I didn't find any example on how to play h264 video using pygame, can someone point me in the right way?

Comment: Take a look at [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html?highlight=format#). I haven't checked it out yet, so no guarantees.

Comment: Doesn't play h264 sadly... checked that out :(

Comment: ok, maybe that was a bit too fast, I couldn't get moviepy to work with an mp4 file and I think the problem is moviepy uses ffmpeg and that is not installed correctly, not even using their imageio downloading mojo.

Comment: I solved the ffmpeg problem and it played the mp4 file. When trying to get a h264 playing it crashed.

Comment: omxplayer may be the solution...

Comment: You can answer your own question if/when you find a solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`Pygame` doesn't currently have support for `H.264` video playback. Try using `Pyglet` instead. (Note: It can only play `.wav` files if you don't install `AVBin`.)

Answer (score 0):

## Play Video in Pygame

Complete Example to PLay Video

```
        import pygame
        import cv2
        import numpy
        pygame.init()
        
        width = 1280
        height = 720
        window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        
        
        class VideoPlayer:
            def __init__(self, surface, x, y, video, play_in_loop=False, mirror_effect=False):
                self.video = video
                self.surface = surface
                self.VideoReader = None
                self.FileOpened = False
                self.x = x
                self.y = y
                self.playInLoop = play_in_loop
                self.open()
                self.FrameResizer = False
                self.mirrorEffect = mirror_effect
        
            def maintainAspectRatio(self):
                video = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video)
                flag, frame = video.read()
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                frame = numpy.rot90(frame)
                frame = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame)
                height = frame.get_height()
                width = frame.get_width()
                self.height = int((self.width * (height/width)))
                video.release()
        
            def activeMirrorEffact(self):
                self.mirrorEffect = True
        
            def deactiveMirrorEffact(self):
                self.mirrorEffect = False
        
            def activeFrameResizer(self, width=600, height=600, aspectRatio=False):
                self.FrameResizer = True
                self.width = width
                self.height = height
                if aspectRatio:
                    self.maintainAspectRatio()
        
            def deactiveFrameResizer(self):
                self.FrameResizer = False
        
            def open(self):
                try:
                    self.VideoReader = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video)
                    self.VideoReader.setExceptionMode(False)
                except:
                    self.FileOpend = False
                    return False
                self.FileOpend = True
        
            def close(self):
                self.VideoReader.release()
                self.FileOpend = False
        
            def show(self):
                if self.FileOpend:
                    flag, frame = self.VideoReader.read()
                    if flag:
                        if not self.mirrorEffect:
                            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        
                        if self.FrameResizer:
                            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.width, self.height), fx=0, fy=0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        frame = numpy.rot90(frame)
                        frame = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame)
                        self.surface.blit(frame, (self.x, self.y))
                    else:
                        self.close()
                        if self.playInLoop:
                            self.open()
        
        
        videoPlayer = VideoPlayer(window, 0, 0, "video.mp4", True)
        videoPlayer.activeFrameResizer(600, aspectRatio=True)
        
        run = True
        while run:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
        
            videoPlayer.show()
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)
```

Step 1: import cv2, NumPy

Step 2: Just Copy 'VideoPlayer' Class

```
        class VideoPlayer:
            def __init__(self, surface, x, y, video, play_in_loop=False, mirror_effect=False):
                self.video = video
                self.surface = surface
                self.VideoReader = None
                self.FileOpened = False
                self.x = x
                self.y = y
                self.playInLoop = play_in_loop
                self.open()
                self.FrameResizer = False
                self.mirrorEffect = mirror_effect

            def maintainAspectRatio(self):
                video = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video)
                flag, frame = video.read()
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                frame = numpy.rot90(frame)
                frame = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame)
                height = frame.get_height()
                width = frame.get_width()
                self.height = int((self.width * (height/width)))
                video.release()

            def activeMirrorEffact(self):
                self.mirrorEffect = True

            def deactiveMirrorEffact(self):
                self.mirrorEffect = False

            def activeFrameResizer(self, width=600, height=600, aspectRatio=False):
                self.FrameResizer = True
                self.width = width
                self.height = height
                if aspectRatio:
                    self.maintainAspectRatio()

            def deactiveFrameResizer(self):
                self.FrameResizer = False

            def open(self):
                try:
                    self.VideoReader = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video)
                    self.VideoReader.setExceptionMode(False)
                except:
                    self.FileOpend = False
                    return False
                self.FileOpend = True

            def close(self):
                self.VideoReader.release()
                self.FileOpend = False

            def show(self):
                if self.FileOpend:
                    flag, frame = self.VideoReader.read()
                    if flag:
                        if not self.mirrorEffect:
                            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

                        if self.FrameResizer:
                            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.width, self.height), fx=0, fy=0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        frame = numpy.rot90(frame)
                        frame = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame)
                        self.surface.blit(frame, (self.x, self.y))
                    else:
                        self.close()
                        if self.playInLoop:
                            self.open()
```

Step 3: That's How You will Make Object of Video Player

```
        videoPlayer = VideoPlayer(Surface, x_position, y_position, video_file, Pass True if You want to play in a loop, Pass True if you Want to enable mirror effect)
```

**If you want to resize video**
if 'aspectratio' is True then it will maintain the aspectRatio according to the width that you have passed by default it will be False

```
        videoPlayer.activeFrameResizer(width, height, aspectRatio=True)
```